# Kendo Chart: Log Y-Axis Major Tick label issue

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-chart

I am using Kendo Chart for plotting data points using Scatter Line chart with dual Y - Axis & both X/Y axis of type "LOG" scale.

Everything were working fine in all browsers until today, I noticed in Chrome browser ONLY - Y axis scale starts with 0.000009999999999999 (instead of 0.00001). please find attached screenshot.

[image]

This rendering issue is not happening for other Y-axis. Before rendering I am setting axes MIN/MAX/AXISCROSSINGVALUE for each axes.

Also, please suggest alternative method for formatting Y-Axis tick label.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function for plotting the scale. Add the function to you axis data.

```
yAxis: {
            name: " name",
            title: {
                text: "bla",
                font: "10px Open Sans",
                color: "#4D4D4D"
            },
            labels: {
                format: "{0:N0}"
            },
            min: 10,
            max: 10000,
            type: "log",
            data: mySequence()
        },
```

Then you function can be a simple loop (this is just a example i´ve made)

```
 function mySequence() {
        var arr = [];
        var n = 1;
        while (n < 10000) {
            n = n * 10;
            arr.push(n);
        }            
        return arr;
    }
```

mind the type: "log" definition since it´s a logarithmic scale